# Run matlab command in terminal

Tags: bash, matlab

I tried to launch this matlab command on terminal to get the path where are located the external library:

```
your_path = [matlabroot '/extern/include'];
```

I use this the following command for launch the command:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop 'command'
```

but I have this error:

> bad pattern: [matlabroot

Comment: `your_path = [matlabroot '/extern/include'];` is not a valid `bash` command. maybe look here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93739-how-do-i-launch-matlab-on-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run that `[matlabroomt '/extern/include']` statement inside your Matlab code, not directly on the shell command line. Make sure you get your quotes right!

```
matlab -batch 'disp([matlabroot ''/extern/include''])'
```

Then you can capture it in a shell variable if you want to use it in something else:

```
mat_include_path=$(matlab -batch 'disp([matlabroot ''/extern/include''])')
```